# Add unique index. SQLite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, ddl, unique-index

I need to add a unique field index to an existing table. I made this row:

```
ALTER TABLE auth_user ADD UNIQUE INDEX (email);
```

The table and the field are already exist. 
The error is:

> Query Error: near "UNIQUE": syntax error Unable to execute statement

What am I missed? Did it have any specific requirements for SQLite3?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS MyUniqueIndexName ON auth_user (email)
```

Also, read the official manual:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html